# Is there an empty data class in SystemVerilog that is similar to "Object" in Java?

Tags: class, system-verilog

I was wondering if SystemVerilog has a generic class handler similar to how Java has an "Object" class or how C has a void*?

If so, what is it called?  What I'm trying to do is have a class that when it is instantiated is passed a defined object, however it could be any object.  So, I'm hoping that I can have an empty handler to this unknown data class (or generic) and I'm hoping that I don't have to create an empty data class and use one that is already part of the SystemVerilog library.

I should add that I'm not using UVM or any other methodologies, otherwise I would have just started from a uvm_component or uvm_object.

Comment: No, there is no such thing in system System Verilog. You have to create your own basic class.

Comment: You could parameterize your class based on the type of the object that will be passed, assuming it is known at compile time.

Comment: Hey Justin, this sounds like a good answer.  I know that we can pull this off in other languages such as C++, but I'm unsure how this works in SystemVerilog.  I thought that parameterization of a class was used in the instantiation of the class and the parameter passed would help define things such as variable/array lengths.  For example, if I needed a bus width then I could parameterize my class and pass the width to the value that I need.  But I've never passed in a class or a class type/definition as a parameter.   How do you do that?

Comment: Are you referring to this: doulos.com/knowhow/systemverilog/systemverilog-tutorials/… The example would be "class Channel #(type Tr = bit);"?

Answer (score 0):

Java's `Object` class is the root base class of all classes. There is no such root class in SystemVerilog.

The UVM's `uvm_object` provides the functionality you are looking for and I suggest using it if for nothing else.